# Negative coordinates in onAreaTouched using AndEngine

Tags: java, android, andengine

I have a Rectangle with the size of the screen with a touchEvent. It works fine.
Then I have an Entity attached to the Rectangle to which I attach some Sprites that are my buttons.

The problem is that, when I show the point I get after onAreaTouched is called in the Sprites, I am getting negative points like (-200, 10). So I am not able to locate the event in the Rectangle.

Is there any problem with Entity for placing other objects or an explanation of my negative coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

may be you are receiving information coordinates referenced to the rectangle?

can you show some code?

Comment: Code is quite long and labyrinthine. Coordinates at the rectagle are ok. They seem to break when pass through the Entity. I will try to change Entity by an Sprite to see what happens.